# Using variables outside of sass files in a React project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I am install sass lib in my React project.

I created a `main.sass` file where I included other sass files by type of `color_variables`. These variables are visible in this file, but when I import the main.sass file itself into JS files and try to access the variables through it, I get an error that the variable was not found. I didn't include sass in webpack dependencies, wanted to try without it.

**main.sass**

```
@import "color_variables"
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap')

*
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

body
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif
    background: $background
```

**color_variables.sass**

```
$black:#1c1c1c
$accent: #cc33ff
$grey:#bab3bc
$borders: #e1dfe2
$background: #fafafa
$white:#ffffff
```

**Error when trying to access a variable while main.sass is imported**

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the variable. Below is the example.

```
//colors
$black: #000000;
$white: #ffffff;
$zanah: #e0efdc;
$aquaDeep: #02433c;
$whiteSand : f6f6f6;


:export {
  zanah: $zanah;
}
```

Comment: I import main.sass in the root index that contains the application, but I still need to explicitly access main.sass inside sass files, otherwise it gives the same error (even with export).
Maybe I'm expecting something that this React implementation can't give me, but I did the same in a VUE project with Vite and this implementation worked

Comment: In your component where you are using the variable you need to import main.sass. Try this out

Comment: Yes, in this case it works even without export in the variable file. I just wanted to achieve the effect so that it was possible to use a variable without explicitly importing it into a file (only with importing the main file in the root index)

Comment: Let me know if you find that way :p

Answer (score 0):

you should use @use instead of @import

```
@use 'color_variables' as CV;
```

then add those variables like this..

```
background: CV.$background;
```

Comment: this also does not work if you export a file with @use to another file